# Flutter Provider returning null value

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

When i am trying to access value  which is stored already inside provider variable, value is returning null ,i am trying to get accestoken ,value is returning in its defined class

```
enum IconListProviderState { idle, loading, loaded, error }

class IconListProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<IconListModelData> iconListCollections = [];

  IconListProviderState currenstState = IconListProviderState.idle;

  static IconListProvider instance = IconListProvider();

  Future<void> FetchIconData() async {
    AuthProvider authProvider = AuthProvider();
    authProvider.fetchUserData();
   var token =await authProvider.accessToken;

    print("acus ${token}");
    currenstState = IconListProviderState.loading;
    notifyListeners();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `fetchUserData()` is the future here.

Try like

```dart
  Future<void> FetchIconData() async {
    AuthProvider authProvider = AuthProvider();
    await authProvider.fetchUserData();
   var token = authProvider.accessToken;//this `await` may not needed
```

Comment: nop,its not returning value

Comment: how are you calling the method to get data

Comment: init() method,i am reloading app everytime also

Comment: this is a future method, you need to await like `await FetchIconData()`